# HTML WYSIWYG editor in Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, html, css, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently started using Eclipse for PHP Development. Please suggest me some HTML WYSIWYG plugin for editing HTML/CSS Templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use APTANA and all your needs will be fullfiled

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of the Eclipse Marketplace shows one that may be what you are looking for called [Tau UI Studio](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tau-ui-studio). *Disclaimer: I personally have not used this plugin.*

Comment: Getting error while downloading it- Unexpected exception while verifying features: 
java.net.MalformedURLException

java.net.MalformedURLException

Answer (score 0):

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) can be used as a standalone application (built on Eclipse) or as an Eclipse plugin. I've been using it for a while and it is a great app for HTML5 projects (HTML, CSS and JS) providing auto-completion, JS debugger, preview window and may other useful tools.
[Mobello editor](http://mobello.github.io/) (formerly TAU UI) is another Eclipse plugin for HTML5 projets (webpages and mobile) with visual WYSIWYG editor, style editor and auto-completion features. I just discovered it and haven't used it yet but by watching the videos in their website I am impressed... It offers a more visual approach than Aptana as you can edit your template from within the preview window.
Both of these plugins are free.

Answer (score -1):

Try to Install Web Page Editor from Eclipse SITE.It has option to drag & drop component & it generates source code also.

Comment: Not really PHP, it's just HTML WYSIWYG doesn't integrate with PHP part (PDT)